# Tippecanoe tile-join tilejson v3 and v3.1

Tags: vector-tiles, tippecanoe

I have merged tiles with tile-join successfully after merging metadata of tilejson changed to v2.
is there any way to set metadata to v3 or v3.1 to tippecanoe.
or another tool which support v3 or v3.1 vector tiles schema?

github issue.
https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe/issues/852

Comment: Cross-post at Github: https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe/issues/852

Comment: yes, i have posted on github also.